# How does the spell Siphon work for a caster who is both spontaneous and able to cast prepared spells?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

If I have a multiclassed spellcaster (both spontaneous and able to cast prepared spells), can I use **Siphon** (*Complete Scoundrel*, p. 102) to regain one or more spell slot/s of any class I wish?

Or

Is the regained spell slot of the same class I have cast Siphon with?

> SIPHON
>
> [...]
>
> You drain the charges from a wand or staff you hold to replace spells
>   you have already cast. As long as the wand or staff has at least 5
>   charges left, you can expend 5 of those charges to replace a cast
>   spell. The spell replaced must be of a level equal to or lower than
>   the highest-level spell the staff or wand holds. If you prepare arcane
>   spells, you can regain any one spell of the affected level that you
>   have already cast that day; if you cast spells spontaneously, you can
>   regain a spell slot of the appropriate level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description of the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell ***siphon*** [trans] (*Complete Scoundrel* 103) makes no mention of any restrictions on what spells it can replace due to the source of the *siphon* spell's casting. That is, the spell doesn't seem to care if it were cast as a prepared spell or if it were cast without preparation. Instead, the description says that the *siphon* spell effect can replace only expended *arcane* prepared spells (like those of a wizard) and expended *arcane* spell slots of a caster that casts spells without preparation (like those of a bard or sorcerer).

Further, with the spell's description including tightly knit language that accommodates casters whose spells are both prepared and not prepared, it seems reasonable to allow a multiclass caster who's capable of both kinds of casting to pick to allocate the spell's effect appropriately however she wants. For example, I'd have no problem in my campaign allowing a sorcerer/wizard to cast the spell *siphon* and use appropriately the effect to replace expended prepared spells, expended spell slots, or both in some combination.

Were the spell to check the caster's magic style—with or without preparation—, activating a ***wand of siphon*** would be complicated as the spell's effect would then possibly be contingent upon the creator of the *wand of siphon* instead of the effect being contingent upon the spell itself. Under such a reading, a typical *wand of siphon* would default to creation by a wizard—as that would give it the lowest caster level—, so a sorcerer could still activate such a wand but receive no benefit. That'd be weird and would perhaps make the *siphon* spell unique among *3.5*'s official spells.